Подсветка синтаксиса работает не полноценно
Описание
Иногда синтаксис не подсвечивается. К примеру, вот тут

Перезагрузка не помогает

Потому что вместо lang-ts надо lang-typescript

@andreymal но в прошлом это работало. Что-то поменяли?

А хотя в форме редактирования работает и lang-ts, странно. То есть тут получается не абстрактное "не полноценно", а различающаяся логика между предпросмотром и сохранённым постом (опять)

А вообще на метамете уже тоже нажаловались https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403526

@andreymal тут удалить вопрос?
